# How to enable Store Pickup as a shipping method in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

Is it already possible via the configuration or do we have to implement the code from this commit?

https://github.com/amenk/magento2/commit/80a2fa4cdce7d968a995f8f64cae9de73891713a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These](http://take.ms/KyjbL) are the only shipping methods available to edit via configuration on a clean m2 install. Though the class exists, I can't find any usages of `\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Pickup` so it's possible magento hasn't implemented it as a carrier just yet.

Comment: I was afraid it was the case :( thanks Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it IS possible to enable Pickup shipping method by creating config file with necessary content to enable it, but still there is a bug in the model class [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/OfflineShipping/Model/Carrier/Pickup.php#L68%22here%22), so you need to rewrite the buggy method first, for example by changing "**carriers/pickup/model**" config to something like "\MyCompany\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Pickup".